# Filtering application in NotificationListenerService

Tags: java, android, android-notifications, notificationservices

i'm using `NotificationListenerService` to retrive the informations from notifications. Actually i can display in a textview only the last notification that i see in the notifications bar. I want, if possible, filter this method and display only the whatsapp notifications. I can get the package name and display it in the LOG but i don't know i do the filter. This is a part of NotificaionListenerService

```
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        Notification mNotification=sbn.getNotification();
        if (mNotification!=null){
            Bundle extras = mNotification.extras;

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.INTENT_ACTION_NOTIFICATION);
            intent.putExtras(mNotification.extras);
            sendBroadcast(intent);

            TAG = "onNotificationPosted";
            Log.i(TAG,"Package Name" + sbn.getPackageName());

            Notification.Action[] mActions=mNotification.actions;
            if (mActions!=null){
                for (Notification.Action mAction:mActions){
                    int icon=mAction.icon;
                    CharSequence actionTitle=mAction.title;
                    PendingIntent pendingIntent=mAction.actionIntent;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

in which i can see the package name of the apps that creates the notifications. Is it there that i have to make the filter? How can i do it? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As simple as doing this:

```
if("com.the.package.name.you.want.to.filter".equals(sbn.getPackageName())) {
     //Do something
}
```

or if there is more than one, you can have them in a hashmap or list, and see if the package
is in there or not.